# Loading AllegroServe

Tags: ubuntu, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to `(require :aserve)` but get this error:

```
 Don't know how to REQUIRE ASERVE.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using SBCL 1.0.57.0 on Ubuntu 12.10. I have the `cl-aserve` package installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I need to `(require :asdf)` first. Then everything works as expected.